# Preciso escrever uma função naipeDeTruco, que dado um naipe, devolva uma lista de strings, uma por cada carta desse naipe seguindo as cartas do truco

Tags: javascript, array, if, for

**DICA:** As cartas incluem todos os números, com exceção das cartas 8 e 9.

O raciocinio que eu tive num primeiro momento foi de criar varios arrays cada um com o nome dos naipes (espadas,paus,ouros e copas) e depois utilizar o comando de repetição FOR para retornar a lista de string. Até finalizar esse racicinio eu achei tranquilo, mas empaquei (literalmente) na parte do FOR e da exclusão das cartas 8 e 9. Alguem pode me ajudar nesse código usando a forma mais simples para inciantes? (estou aprendendo sozinha e pela internet, paciencia rs).

Na parte do FOR eu fiz isso para cada naipe, porem aparecem erros como: (naipeDeTruco faz comparações contra strings) e naipeDeTruco("espadas") NÃO deveria conter o "8 de espadas" - naipeDeTruco(...).indexOf is not a function //

Eu realmente não sei como resolver esse exercicio ainda mais que o erro de comparações contra strings já é recorrente em outros exercicios de condicionais que fiz.

```
    function naipeDeTruco(naipe){
  let espadas = [];
  let copas =   [];
  let ouros =  [];
  let paus  =  [];

for(var i=0; i <13; i++)
  if(naipe === "espadas"){
   naipe =[ i +" "+"de" + naipe] - [ 8 +" "+"de" + naipe] - [ 9 +" "+"de" + naipe];
    return naipe;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que é `naipe` e o que esperas que essa função retorne?

Comment: Naipe é o nome dado às "famílias" ou tipos das cartas de baralho (espadas,paus,ouros e copas). Um exemplo que é dado é: naipeDeTruco("espadas") vai retornar ["1 de espadas", "2 de espadas","3 de espadas" ...,"12 de espadas"]

Comment: Ok, e não retorna Rei, Às, Rainha ou Valete?

Comment: devolva uma lista de strings, uma por cada carta desse naipe seguindo as cartas do truco. Pelo que entendi na questao ele pede todas as cartas de cada naipe mas excluindo as cartas 8 e 9, entao deve entrar sim Rei, Às,Rainha e Valete.

Comment: Qual as cartas e a ordem delas? Elas devem ser devolvidas em ordem de força?

Comment: todas as cartas contidas em um naipe menos as cartas 8 e 9. Não devem ser devolvidas em ordem de força, a unica restrição éque foi dada é sobre cartas 8 e 9. E pelo exemplo dado vai ate 12 cartas. (eu nunca joguei baralho por isso estou mais confusa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O meu código ficou um pouco diferente do seu, ao invés de pedir somente para escrever, coloquei para adicionar ao Array, não precisei criar um array para cada naipe. Está funcionando corretamente!

Meus agradecimentos ao código do colega que perguntou se o curso era da Digital House, que me deu uma luz para resolver!

```js
copas = '♥';
ouros = '♦';
paus = '♣';
espadas = '♠';
function naipeDeTruco(naipe) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    if (i == 8 || i == 9) {
      i = i + 1;
    } else {
      resultado.push(i + " de " + naipe);
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}
console.log(naipeDeTruco(copas));
console.log(naipeDeTruco(ouros));
console.log(naipeDeTruco(paus));
console.log(naipeDeTruco(espadas));
```

Answer (score 3):

A maneira mais lógica, uma vez que o tipo de cartas é pré-defenido é ter uma array "preparada" e retornar somente com indicação do naipe... ou seja:

```js
function naipeDeTruco(naipe) {
  return ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "10", "11", "12", "Valete", "Rainha", "Rei", "Às"].map(function(tipo) {
    return [tipo, naipe].join(' de ');
  });
}

console.log(naipeDeTruco('espadas'));
console.log(naipeDeTruco('copas'));
```

Comment: fiz um teste com teu código e surgiram erros que não entendi.  naipeDeTruco("espadas") deveria ser ["1 de espadas", "2 de espadas"... 
[ '1 de espadas',
  '2 de espadas',
  '3 de espadas',
  '4 de espadas',
  '5 de espadas',
  '6 de espadas',
  '7 de espadas',
   deepEqual [ '1 de espadas',
  '2 de espadas',
  '3 de espadas',
  '4 de espadas',
  '5 de espadas',
  '6 de espadas',
  '7 de espadas',

Comment: @StéphanieVerissimo, acho que vale a pena editar a sua pergunta mostrando como você está fazendo esses testes. ;)

Comment: Descobri o erro! Eu exclui "Valete","Rainha","Rei","Às" para ver se alterava algo e realmente deu certo! Vou pesquisar sobre .join e .map para entender melhor seu código!

Answer (score 2):

Excluindo "Valete","Rainha","Rei","Às" o codigo deu certo!

```js
function naipeDeTruco(naipe) {
  return ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "10", "11", "12"].map(function(tipo) {
    return [tipo, naipe].join(' de ');
  });
}

console.log(naipeDeTruco('espadas'));
console.log(naipeDeTruco('copas'));
```